# Help on pip install?

Tags: python, python3

Please I need help, if I run sudo pip install pip or pip install Django
on my computer terminal, 
this is the message I get, what can I do.

```
Last login: Thu Jun 28 18:51:51 on console
➜  ~  sudo pip install pip
Password:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named pip._internal
➜  ~  pip install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ImportError: No module named pip._internal
```

I have both pycharm and jupyter notebook installed, the jupyter notebook is not responding. Before the pip was working and also the Django, now I don't
know what I have done, my pandas is not working on the jupyter notebook. Please, can someone help me. I downloaded python 3.6 last year but if run python version on the terminal I get python 2.7 and try to download Python 3.6 again a day ago. I don't know if there is some file I have deleted by mistake. This the information I saw on the pycharm if I run the manage.py

```
"Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
                "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
                "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
            ).
```

The output reads

```
/Users/MacBookPro/venv/bin/python Users/MacBookPro/myDjango.py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'Users/MacBookPro/myDjango.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Process finished with exit code 2.
```

Thanks.

Comment: What Ubuntu are you running?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to purge any pip installations and install pip again using this guide: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Thanks to all I used the solution you provided, the pycharm is working now, but the anaconda notebook on my Mac is not recognising the python and the libraries.This is the message I get if I run on the jupyter notebook
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d131f532a621> in <module>()
----> 1 gold = pd.read_csv('gold.csv')
      2 gold

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined

Comment: what version of python are you using?
 (`python --version`)

i never used jupyter notebook, but it could be that it needs to be run using python2 or python3

Comment: okay i just checked, jupyter requires: Python 3.3 or greater, or Python 2.7, so thats probably not the problem :/

Comment: in the [documentation](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) they recommend downloading and installing [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux), maybe you could try out these instructions: https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#id3

Comment: python3.6. the jupyter notebook was working before and now is not working, that code was working fine on the jupyter notebook before but everything just stopped working which I don't know what happened. Please I am very much new in programming still learning on the bases (self learning)

Comment: sry can't help you further, i can give basic suggestions, but thats about it. i don't know what is causing the problem :/

Comment: did you try reinstalling jupyter notebook? do you get any errors while uninstalling it and installing in?

Comment: this sentence was completely unnecessary:
"Please I am very much new in programming still learning on the bases (self learning)"
i learned things by doing, you can too, it just sounds like you are putting yourself into a helpless situation thinking that you cannot improve without the help of others (not that there is something wrong with asking questions), but you are responsible for your learning and you have to do the work and fail and try something else and fail again to really learn :) (just some advice)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't setup the virtual environment.

This article will guide you through how to set one up, what it does, and how to use it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/development_environment